# Google Maps initialize() with new JSON mapOptions won't work

Tags: json, google-maps, initialization, maps

This is the standard Google code and it loads the map fine.

```
var mapOptions = {
            center: { lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 },
            zoom: 8
        };

function initialize() {             
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
            mapOptions);
        }
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

But, after I search an XML file for the values and set them to the mapOptions, it won't initialize for the god of me. I've tried everything.

```
$(xml).find("location").each(function(){ 

                    var lat = $(this).find("lat").text();
                    var lng = $(this).find("lng").text();

                    mapOptions.center.lat = lat;
                    mapOptions.center.lng = lng;

                    initialize();
            });
```

I even added alerts inside the initialize() and they do work with the new coordinates from the XML. Why won't the map load is beyond me...

```
function initialize() {
            alert(mapOptions.center.lat);
            alert(mapOptions.center.lng);

            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
            mapOptions);
        }
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

**SOLUTION:** As the user geocodezip suggested, the solution is to use parseFloat() when setting the variables.

```
var lat = parseFloat($(this).find("lat").text());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get the error `Uncaught InvalidValueError: setCenter: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: in property lat: not a number`.  Note that `zoom` is also a mandatory/required [MapOption](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapOptions).  This works for me:

```
$(xml).find("location").each(function () {

    var lat = parseFloat($(this).find("lat").text());
    var lng = parseFloat($(this).find("lng").text());

    mapOptions.center.lat = lat;
    mapOptions.center.lng = lng;

    initialize();
});
```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tp7qjznz/1/)

code snippet:

```js
var geocoder;
var map;
var mapOptions = {
  center: {},
  zoom: 5
};

function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
    mapOptions);
}

function parseXml(str) {
  if (window.ActiveXObject) {
    var doc = new ActiveXObject('MicrosoftXMLDOM');
    doc.loadXML(str);
    return doc;
  } else if (window.DOMParser) {
    return (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(str, 'text/xml');
  }
}
var xmlData = "<markers><location><lat>45</lat><lng>-72</lng></location></markers>";
var xml = parseXml(xmlData);


$(xml).find("location").each(function() {

  var lat = parseFloat($(this).find("lat").text());
  var lng = parseFloat($(this).find("lng").text());

  mapOptions.center.lat = lat;
  mapOptions.center.lng = lng;

  initialize();
});
```

```css
html,
body,
#map-canvas {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<div id="map-canvas" style="border: 2px solid #3872ac;"></div>
```